# databricks error IllegalStateException: The transaction log has failed integrity checks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a table that I need drop, delete transaction log and recreate, but while I am trying to drop I get following error.

I have ran repair table statement on this one and could be responsible for error but not sure.

> IllegalStateException: The transaction log has failed integrity checks. We recommend you contact Databricks support for assistance. To disable this check, set spark.databricks.delta.state.corruptionIsFatal to false. Failed verification of:
> Table size (bytes) - Expected: 0 Computed: 63233
> Number of files - Expected: 0 Computed: 1

Answer (score 3):

We think this may just be related to s3 eventual consistency. Please try waiting a few extra minutes after deleting the Delta directory before writing new data to it. Also, normal `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` doesn't do anything for Delta, as Delta doesn't use the Hive Metastore to store the partitions. There is an [FSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/fsck.html#fsck-repair-table-delta), but that is for removing the file entries from the transaction log of a Databricks Delta table that can no longer be found in the underlying file system.

We don't recommend overwriting a Delta table in place, like you might with a normal Spark table. Delta is not like a normal table - it's a table, plus a transaction log, and many versions of your data (unless fully vacuumed). If you want to overwrite parts of the table, or even the whole table, you should use Delta's `delete` [functionality](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#delete). If you want to completely change the table, consider writing to an entirely new directory, such as `/table/v2/...` and separately deleting the other table.

Comment: can also look at `replaceWhere` - https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#overwrite-using-dataframes

Comment: Thanks for your help, what ever i try i get the same error IllegalStateException: The transaction log has failed integrity checks. We recommend you contact Databricks support for assistance. To disable this check, set spark.databricks.delta.state.corruptionIsFatal to false. Failed verification of:
Table size (bytes) - Expected: 0 Computed: 63233
Number of files - Expected: 0 Computed: 1

Answer (score 3):

To skip the issue from occurring can use below command (PySpark notebook):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.state.corruptionIsFatal", False)
```